# Script to change color of image files

Tags: macos, shell, automation, applescript

I have lot of image files (png) in a folder on my mac. They are all same color (say blue) and I would like to change their color to another same color (assume some RGB value that i already know).

Is it possible to achieve it through a script? shell script, applescript etc.

Until now, i have been doing this through online color editor tool ( http://pixlr.com/editor/ ). That is, open these files (png files) in this online editor and select one at a time and open "Color balance" dialog and set the same RGB value (say 20,30,40) for each file and save it.

This is a repetitive task and I would like to automate it using some script or free app tool on mac. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

[Color modification with ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/)